# Associate two elements of different tables in the db

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how much to explain this, so I'll give my situation and so you can understand me better.

I have a games webpage. In my db, I have two tables: one with my games (with colums like id, name, description, **category** *(this is a number, not a string)*, etc.), and another with my categories (with the id and the name).
When I upload games, instead of assigning into the category column the name of the category, I assign a number, the one which corresponds in the categories table (I do it with a select option like this:

```
<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>
```

(This is inside a select tag (inside a form) and with a foreach statement so it shows me all the options).

So now, what I want is that when I catch the games from the db with a 'SELECT * FROM games', if I call the category element, instead of getting the id of the category, to assign the id with the category name... I don't know how much to explain it but I hope you can understand me.

So, what should I use?

Comment: Lookup `join`. You have to join the two tables in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use just "INNER JOIN or JOIN" to get the result from two tables by just joining them.

```
`SELECT g.*,c.*
 FROM games g
 INNER JOIN categories c on c.categoryid = g.categoryid;`
```

this will give you just those which are associated categories.
but if you use "Left Join" it would give you everything from games(http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

```
`SELECT g.*,c.*
 FROM games g
 LEFT JOIN categories c on c.categoryid = g.categoryid;`
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide! I'll take a look and if I have a problem, I'll tell you! ;)

Comment: Okay, I've used this code 'SELECT g.*, c.*
        FROM games g
        LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.id = g.category
        ORDER BY name', but now, if I want to call it with a foreach statement, how can I do it? I mean foreach ($result as $row) and then call it like $row['g.name']?

Comment: you can use in the query
select g.name as name, g.categoryid as cid,c.categoryname as catName (this is called alias and can use it towards any column if you use the same name as g.categoryname as catName and c.categoryname as catName then it assumes second alias as catName2 )
and in foreach $row['name'] and $row['cid']

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` to pull the category name. Example:

```
SELECT 
  g.id g_id,
  g.name g_name,
  g.desc g_desc,
  c.name c_name
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN
  categories c
    ON c.id = g.category
```

This is an example, you'll need to select the proper columns and assign a unique alias.

Comment: Oh, thanks! But actually, I don't understand so much that thing of the g.id g_id, g.name g_name... How do I have to use it?

Comment: `g.id` would be the `id` column in `games`, for example. You need to specify your own columns here.

Comment: Oh, sorry... Also, `g_id` is the *alias* of `g.id`, so you can refer to it later. Aliases are useful if you were querying the game and category id (assuming the `id` column exists in both tables). If you didn't assign an alias, then the `id` column in the result set would be the last `id` queried (so it gets overwritten every time you select it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to join the tables so you can get the categoryname from the same query.

You can do it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games, category WHERE games.category = categoyry.id) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['games.name'].' '.$row['category.name'];
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention I use PDO for my connection!

Comment: @peregraum just check how to do the join with pdo then and you will succeed ;)